# Cannot connect to docker container webapp from different system

Tags: docker

If I run my docker container as

docker run -ti --privileged=true -p 5010:5000 myapp

I cannot connect to myapp by https://:5010

But if I run my docker container as

docker run -ti --privileged=true -p 5000:5000 myapp

I can connect to myapp by https://:5000 from different machine

What can be the issue? What option should I use to map container port to host port with different number?

output of nestat
[image]

Interestingly I can connect to my web server from same machine by wget command

This is the output of the netstat -ln when my docker is running.
[image]

Comment: https: //ipaddr:5010 cannot connect bu https: //ipaddr:5000 can connect

Comment: Could it be something else already listening on `5010` on the host machine? try a `netstat -ln`.

Comment: What IP address are you actually trying to connect to?  What error do you get when you try to connect?

Comment: @FrankNielsen   I have tried with many different ports, ufw status shows it's inactive.

Comment: can you show a `docker ps`?

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
6341079539c9        myapp3            "/lib/systemd/system…"   37 minutes ago      Up 37 minutes       0.0.0.0:5044->5000/tcp   confident_jennings

Comment: Update your question with the `docker ps` output, thats better and more readable ;)

Comment: and also do a `netstat -ln` on the docker host and show output in your question

Comment: @FrankNielsen updated output of netstat -ln and other observation

Comment: On the host, can you connect to your docker container `5000/5010` with the host lan ip (eth0) address. If you can connect to the container, but `netstat -ln` is not listing the port - my guess it is something in the *iptbles*.

Answer (score 0):

This has been finally identified as firewall issue and the ports can be accessed if the firewall rule is changed.